# Using mongoose timestamps option does not create properties

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, timestamp, robo3t

I may be missing something obvious, but have read to docs.I had an existing collection. Using Robo3T, I dropped it. In my script, running out of Node, I have defined the schema adding timestamps option as shown below. I run my app. The collection is created. However, there are no timestamps when I view via Robo. Everything else is as I expect. The indices are created. The fields are populated.

I expected two additional properties: createdAt and updatedAt.

I am using mongoose 5.2.7.

```
    const categorySchema = mongoose.Schema(
        {
            value: String,
            recordName: String,
            sourceId: Number,
            targetId: Number,
            requestParameters: Object,
            magentoResponse: Object
        },
        {
            autoIndex: true
        }, 
        {
            timestamps: true
        }
    );

    categorySchema.index({sourceId: 1}, {unique: true});
    categorySchema.index({targetId: 1, recordName: 1}, {unique: true});
```

Answer (score 3):

Oh! I was being an idiot. autoIndex and timestamps should be in the same block. I was being an idiot!

It should have been:

```
const categorySchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        value: String,
        recordName: String,
        sourceId: Number,
        targetId: Number,
        requestParameters: Object,
        magentoResponse: Object
    },
    {
        autoIndex: true,
        timestamps: true
    }
);

categorySchema.index({sourceId: 1}, {unique: true});
categorySchema.index({targetId: 1, recordName: 1}, {unique: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you re-create those records? If they did not go though mongoose (but via mongoDB client/cli) they would not have those fields. These are [mongoose specific](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps).

And are created when you create a new Model and save it:

```
var thingSchema = new Schema({..}, { timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at' } });
var Thing = mongoose.model('Thing', thingSchema);
var thing = new Thing();
thing.save(); // `created_at` & `updatedAt` will be included
```